# flutter image cropper can't crop images

Tags: flutter

I downloaded enigma project using this [Github](https://github.com/AmitJoki/Enigma) link. It has image crop function using [image_cropper](https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper)  from pub.dev so when I trying to run this project I am getting an error from this part.

```
Future<Null> _cropImage() async {
    double x, y;
    if (widget.profile) {
      x = 1.0;
      y = 1.0;
    }
    File croppedFile = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
        sourcePath: _imageFile.path,
        ratioX: x,
        ratioY: y,
        circleShape: widget.profile,
        toolbarColor: Colors.white);
    setState(() {
      if (croppedFile != null) _imageFile = croppedFile;
    });
  }
```

It says

> The named parameter 'ratioX' isn't defined. Try correcting the name to
> an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with
> the name 'ratioX'

but it's the same as the original project.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Enigma.getNTPWrappedWidget(WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: enigmaBlack,
        appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text(widget.title),
            backgroundColor: enigmaBlack,
            actions: _imageFile != null
                ? <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.edit, color: enigmaWhite),
                        disabledColor: Colors.transparent,
                        onPressed: () {
                          _cropImage();
                        }),
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.check, color: enigmaWhite),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            isLoading = true;
                          });
                          widget.callback(_imageFile).then((imageUrl) {
                            Navigator.pop(context, imageUrl);
                          });
                        }),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 8.0,
                    )
                  ]
                : []),
        body: Stack(children: [
          new Column(children: [
            new Expanded(child: new Center(child: _buildImage())),
            _buildButtons()
          ]),
          Positioned(
            child: isLoading
                ? Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          valueColor:
                              AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(enigmaBlue)),
                    ),
                    color: enigmaBlack.withOpacity(0.8),
                  )
                : Container(),
          )
        ]),
      ),
      onWillPop: () => Future.value(!isLoading),
    ));
  }
```

crop image method uses here..

Answer (score 1):

Image Cropper library had parameters called ratioX and ratioY, but it has been changed in recent versions.

Check the CHANGELOG of the libary at version 1.1.0:

> BREAKING CHANGE: ratioX and ratioY are replaced by aspectRatio,
> circleShape is replaced by cropStyle, removed toolbarTitle and
> toolbarColor (these properties are moved into AndroidUiSettings)